Asymptotic ergodicity of independent subsequences
Let $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a real-valued stochastic process that is ergodic in the following asymptotic sense. $X_n\rightarrow X_\infty$ in distribution and the time averages converge to the asymptotic ensemble average,
$$\overline{X}_N = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N X_n \rightarrow \mathbb{E}X_\infty \quad\text{almost surely as } N\rightarrow\infty.$$
Let $\{W_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a binary-valued stochastic process with $W_n \in \{0, 1\}$. We call $W_n$ the event selection process, as $W_n = 1$ marks the occurrence of events.
Define $K_i$ as the $i$th time when $W_n = 1$:
$$ K_i = n \iff W_1+W_2+\cdots+W_n = i, W_n=1 $$
Assume also that $W_n=1$ happens infinitely often to ensure that there will always be another event.
Let $Y_i = X_{K_i}$, that is, $Y_i$ is the value of the process $\{X_n\}$ at the time when the $i$th event occurs.
I'm trying to show that if $\{X_n\}$ and $\{W_n\}$ are independent, then $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is also asymptotically ergodic: $\overline{Y}_N \rightarrow \mathbb{E}X_\infty$ almost surely.
My approach:

Consider events $B_m = \left\{\big|\overline{Y}_m-\mathbb{E}X_\infty\big| \geq \epsilon\right\}$ and try to bound their probabilities such that $\sum_{m=1}^\infty P(B_m) < \infty$. From here the result would follow by application of the Borel-Cantelli lemma, which states that almost surely only finitely many of $B_m$ happen if the sum of their probabilities is finite.
To evaluate $P(B_m)$ consider the set of all increasing $m$-long subsequences of positive integers : $S_m^N=\{(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_m) : 1\leq n_1 < n_2 < \cdots < n_m=N\}$. Enumerating over $N$ gives all the possible outcomes of $(K_1,K_2,\ldots,K_m)$, so using the independence of $\{X_n\}$ and $\{W_n\}$ we obtain
$$P(B_m) = \sum_{N=1}^\infty\sum_{(n_1,\ldots,n_m)\in S_m^N} P(\big|\overline{X}_{n_1,\ldots,n_m}-\mathbb{E}X_\infty\big| \geq\epsilon)P(K_1=n_1,\ldots,K_m=n_m)$$
where $\overline{X}_{n_1,\ldots,n_m} = \sum_{i=1}^m X_{n_i}/m$ is the subsequence average.
For each $m$ we can split the sum over $N$ at some cutoff point $N_0=N_0(m)$
$$P(B_m) \leq \sum_{N=1}^{N_0}\sum_{(n_1,\ldots,n_m)\in S_m^N} P(\big|\overline{X}_{n_1,\ldots,n_m}-\mathbb{E}X_\infty\big|\geq\epsilon) + 2^{-m}$$
This uses the fact that sparse subsequences $K_1,\ldots,K_m$ must get arbitrarily rare to ensure the total probability is finite (details omitted). It now remains to find a similar bound for the sum up to $N_0$ that gets tighter as $m$ increases. The problem is that $N_0$ increases with $m$, so the number of terms in the above sum increases, so I'm not sure if using this $N_0$ cutoff is even useful.
To continue, we must obviously somehow use the (asymptotic) ergodicity of $\{X_N\}$, which says that for all $m$ and almost all outcomes $\omega\in\Omega$ there exists $N_1=N_1(m,\omega)$ such that for all $N>N_1$,
$ \left|\overline{X}_N - \mathbb{E}X_\infty\right| < 2^{-m} $. Now, using the identity $X_N = N\overline{X}_N - (N-1)\overline{X}_{N-1}$ we can derive the bound
$$ \left|X_N - \mathbb{E}X_\infty\right| < (1+2N)2^{-m} $$
which also holds for $N>N_1$ for all $m$ and almost all $\omega$. This is obviously useless if $N_1 \geq N_0$, and if $N_1 < N_0$ we can apply it to subsequences to lower the sum cutoff point. However $N_1$ also depends on $m$ so the finiteness of the sum up to $N_1$ is also not guaranteed. This is where I run out of further ideas to explore.

